# I want to get the "Index array" from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I create a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
    List<int> indexList = GetFromSomewher()
    Results = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(System.Double),indexList.ToArray() );

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        List<int> indexInstance = new List<int>();
        for (int d = 0; d < DegreesOfFreedom; d++)
        {
            indexInstance.Add(DimDict[d][row.Field<double>(d)]);
        }
        Results.SetValue(row.Field<double>(DegreesOfFreedom), indexInstance.ToArray());
    }
```

Then, once created I want to see the index array and the value. BUT this only gives me the "value". I can see the index array in debug - but can't access it.

```
    foreach (var res in Results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the humble for loop!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[][] test = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new int[] { 7, 8, 9 } };

         for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < test[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Index: [{i},{j}]: {test[i][j]}");
            }
        }
    }
```